# Problema con "npm start" React Project

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, react-native, npm

Lo que pasa, cree un proyecto de inicio con "create-react-app" despues de unos dias, y querer volver a operar con el, al ejecutar el comando "npm start" dentro del proyecto me lanza el siguiente error: (Cabe mencionar que estoy en linux)

> Starting the development server...
>
> ```
> events.js:174
>       throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>       ^
>
> Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/public'
>     at FSWatcher.start (internal/fs/watchers.js:165:26)
>     at Object.watch (fs.js:1253:11)
>     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:38:15)
>     at setFsWatchListener (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
>     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._watchWithNodeFs (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:233:14)
>     at FSWatcher.NodeFsHandler._handleDir (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:429:19)
>     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:477:19)
>     at FSWatcher.<anonymous> (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:482:16)
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
> Emitted 'error' event at:
>     at FSWatcher._handleError (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/index.js:260:10)
>     at createFsWatchInstance (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:40:5)
>     at setFsWatchListener (/home/keegan/Documents/Github/learn-react-redux/webdev/node_modules/chokidar/lib/nodefs-handler.js:81:15)
>     [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
>     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:154:5)
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 1
> npm ERR! webdev@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
> npm ERR! Exit status 1
> npm ERR! 
> npm ERR! Failed at the webdev@0.1.0 start script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /home/keegan/.npm/_logs/2019-04-11T21_31_37_836Z-debug.log
> ```

No he encontrado solucion alguna, opte por borrar la carpeta de "node_modules", al dar nuevamente "npm install" me percate de que se encontraron "vulnerabilidades" al revisar estas con el comando "npm audit" la mayoria por no decir que todas, se relacionan con el comando "react-script"

[image: Parte del Scan de "npm audit"]

Comment: No sé sinceramente que pueda estar ocurriendo, pero viendo que el error dice que has alcanzado el número máximo de archivos que puede observar el observador, te hago una pregunta, ¿Por qué no reinicias el equipo? Solo para descartar temas de memoria, y que caso de que no funcione, entonces podrías buscar una forma de decirle al watcher u observador que aumente el número de archivos que puede vigilar

Comment: @GermanAlzate Ya lo revise, y si, efectivamente era la situación ejecute el comando `echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p` Ejecute el proyecto (Aun que demora en abrirlo) y funciono nuevamente, reiniciare la PC para ver si tengo mejores resultados... gracias!